# Declaring a function without contents ; - and then with contents {} - c++

Tags: c++, function, overloading, declaration

I am not sure of the terminology so I don't know how to word my title; if someone wants to edit it with the correct terminology that would be fine.

When I code something, I always do it, i guess chronologically. I put my main down the bottom and then work up. However, I recently read a tutorial that did something I haven't seen before.

At the top, after the includes, the programmer wrote:

```
void inccell(int pos, int width, unsigned char *board);
void deccell(int pos, int width, unsigned char *board);
```

I haven't seen this before; I always do `void myfunction (args) { stuff }`. I haven't seen it in this context with a `;`. After this, further down in the program he defines the contens of the function:

```
void inccell(int pos, int width, unsigned char *board)
{
    ++board[(pos-width)-1];
    ++board[ pos-width   ];
    ++board[ pos-width +1];
    ++board[ pos-1       ];
    ++board[ pos+1       ];
    ++board[(pos+width)-1];
    ++board[ pos+width   ];
    ++board[ pos+width+1 ];

    return;
}

void deccell(int pos, int width, unsigned char *board)
{
    --board[(pos-width)-1];
    --board[ pos-width   ];
    --board[ pos-width +1];
    --board[ pos-1       ];
    --board[ pos+1       ];
    --board[(pos+width)-1];
    --board[ pos+width   ];
    --board[ pos+width+1 ];

    return;
}
```

The arguments of the functions with `;` and `{ }` are the same, so as far as I know it isn't to 'overload'; I believe overloading is used so one can call a function with different sets of arguments, i.e. `myfunc(myint, mystr, mybool)` and `myfunc(myint, mystr)` could both be valid.

I'm probably wrong in that statement.

However, could someone please explain to me why he declares the functions at the top, if he's not overloading, and what the purpose of it is?

Thanks.

Comment: Any C++ tutorial will tell you that those are *prototypes* of the functions.

Comment: One's a (forward) declaration, and the other is a definition.

Comment: It is just forward declaration, and he defines the code after the main,I think for clarity.

Comment: @0x499602D2 apparently, there is a faster way than reading tutorials. 2 answers already...

Comment: @0x499602D2 Oh yes, I've seen this in tutorials ;). The example is even FROM a tutorial. However, most people assume you already know the terminologies and hence don't explain their use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are function *declarations*. They simply inform the compiler about the existence and the signature of those functions, so that their definition can appear after the point of call:

```
void foo(); // DECLARATION

int main()
{
    foo(); // CALL (would be illegal without the declaration, because the compiler
           //       wouldn't know about foo(), since it hasn't met its definition yet)
}

#include <iostream>

void foo() // DEFINITION
{ 
    std::cout << "Hello, world!"; 
}
```

Comment: I see... So essentially, whereas I've been coding things 'chronologically', so main is down the bottom, things i'm calling are up a little higher, and so on, in order for the compiler to know about the functions, by declaring the functions first, this allows me to avoid the slightly annoying process of determining where I need to place my function? 
Also, is that the only reason? Does it increase speed (or decrease it)? And does this work in plain old C?

Comment: @Anteara: Yes, it works the same way as in C, and it has nothing to do with performance. It just informs the compiler about the existence of a function that would otherwise not be found

Comment: Alright, so in effect when it comes to the compiled program, it would virtually be the exact same thing as had I simply rearranged the order of my functions. There is no performance difference, it's simply done for clarity or for simplicity sake?

Answer (score 1):

He is the declaring function first then defining it.

The forward declaration is needed when the function is used before the definition. (Its mandatory)

if the function is defined at top then the function declaration is not necessary.

It is used for the compiler to check whether the datatypes of arguments mathch, filling address where the function is called (BACKPATHCHING) ...